# Sub-graph Id a good candidate for a label in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j for thousands of relatively small 20-2000 node sub-graph that will be disconnected from each. Each of these graphs is considered its own workspace that should only be visible to certain users.

Would it be reasonable to use the unique workspace id as a label to group each of these sub-graphs together?

What implication on indexing might this have because this label would be unique to each sub-graph?

Answer (score 1):

multi-tenancy is not well supported yet in Neo4j.
It would help if you could describe some of your query use-cases.

If you have disconnected subgraphs anyway, it would probably be enough to just index your "root" node or an entry point to your subgraph, with "Workspace" and the workspace id label?

Then you can traverse out from that node.

Neo4j supports up to 32k labels afaik, but I think they become slower if you use too many as it has to use an indirection then if the label-id gets bigger (depending on how many other labels you store on the nodes as well). Probably worth a performance test.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Michael. It sounds like a Workspace label with workspaceid on a root node is better suited for my purposes. Generally I would want to display the whole workspace to the user. Most of use cases would be retrieving the whole worksqpce (with 99% workspaces being under 100 nodes with the potential for 2k nodes in some cases) and filtering the workspace based on user input. I was thinking about putting a workspaceid on every node but it does not sound like it is necessary.